# Run whole application as another user (other user than root)

Tags: linux, mongodb, daemon, sudo, sudoers

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/mongodb-org-server.postinst
I could see in the above link that mongodb has created a newuser named 'mongodb'.and I got to know that many bigger projects run their project as a custom user (here as a user 'mongodb').I wrote a small application in python and running it as sudo right now,I would like to create a new custom user for my application and run the application as the custom user.how does actually bigger projects acheive this .what is the command they use to make run the whole application or package as a custom user?
In a whole lot reading about this I found that we could use `sudo -u <username> <command>`
or by setting euid or uid by `seteuid()` function. but I want to know how actually real projects implement it and follow that standard way in my project.

Answer (score 0):

As in the file you linked they change the owner of the executable to their custom 
using `chown` so you could use that in a post-installation script (a script that will configure what is necessary for your application to run correctly)

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/mongod.service here they configured the user

Comment: Check the link you added in the original post. They use `chown` to change the user of the executable.